# Realm 1.0 not compiling for OS X - 'No matching function for call to RLMNotificationBlock'

Tags: macos, realm

my apologies for asking this here. I upgraded Realm on my OS X project yesterday from .98 up to 1.0 via cocoapods and I am now unable to compile my project. The compiler hits the following lines in RLMResults.mm :

```
// The compiler complains about the method's argument type not matching due to
// it not having the generic type attached, but it doesn't seem to be possible
// to actually include the generic type
// http://www.openradar.me/radar?id=6135653276319744
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wmismatched-parameter-types"
- (RLMNotificationToken *)addNotificationBlock:(void (^)(RLMResults *, NSError *))block {
    [_realm verifyNotificationsAreSupported];
    return RLMAddNotificationBlock(self, _results, block, false);
}
```

So it seems as if the #pragma calls are there to have the compiler ignore issues, but I still can't compile: It highlights the return RLMNotificationBlock line with a 'No matching function for call to RLMAddNotificationBlock' error.  When this happened to me yesterday, I had thought that maybe I was needing to update Xcode and my OS for compatibility reasons, but I am now on OS 10.11.5 and Xcode 7.3.1 and I am still having this issue.

Again, my apologies for what might be a dumb question, but at the moment I am dead in the water, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried to make a clean build since upgrading your system and toolchain?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Marius. I think I've got it figured out - it looks like adding a notification block to a result is a bit different in 1.0 than it was in .98 - my code was missing a RLMCollectionChange parameter and then rather than flagging the user code it flagged the source file instead(?) but now that I have changed my block calls it looks as if I am back up.

Comment: Even though I can confirm this change, the error you were facing is really misleading. Thanks for updating the question here. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I've got it. Changing my calls to adding a notification block to a result array to include a RLMCollectionChange parameter (which apparently wasn't needed in .98?) is now compiling. For some reason the complier was pointing to the issue being in the RealmResults.mm file rather than an incorrect signature on my part calling it.  Thank you!